# Loop to label tokens with their corresponding value in r

Tags: r, string

This should be pretty simple; however, I can't get it right.
I got the followin list:

```
list <- list(c("sofa", "couch"), 
         c("fridge"),
         c("desk", "table", "brown"),
         c("window", "clean"),
         c("speaker"))
```

Which I am trying to convert to the following format (as a dataframe)

```
table <- data.frame(word = c("sofa", "couch", "fridge", "desk", "table", "brown", "window", "clean", "speaker"),
                label = c("sofa couch", "sofa couch", 
                          "fridge", 
                          "desk table brown", "desk table brown", "desk table brown",
                          "window clean",
                          "window clean",
                          "speaker"))
```

I created this loop which makes sense to me but it is not working. I can't figure out why or if this is the best way of doing it

```
table <- data.frame(word = character(), label = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
value <- 0

for(i in 1:length(list)){
  for(j in 1:length(list[[i]])){
    value <- c(list[[i]][j], str_c(list[[i]], collapse = " "))
    table <- rbind(table, value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could `unlist` the `list` to get `word` and repeat the concatenated elements  of each `list` based on their lengths.

```
data.frame(word = unlist(list), 
           label = rep(sapply(list, paste, collapse = " "), lengths(list)))

#     word            label
#1    sofa       sofa couch
#2   couch       sofa couch
#3  fridge           fridge
#4    desk desk table brown
#5   table desk table brown
#6   brown desk table brown
#7  window     window clean
#8   clean     window clean
#9 speaker          speaker
```

Comment: Thanks, you responded quite fast. I was going to delete the question as while editting the question for some mistakes I actually found the answer. However, your solution is more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `stack`

```
stack(setNames(list, sapply(list, paste, collapse = " ")))
#   values              ind
#1    sofa       sofa couch
#2   couch       sofa couch
#3  fridge           fridge
#4    desk desk table brown
#5   table desk table brown
#6   brown desk table brown
#7  window     window clean
#8   clean     window clean
#9 speaker          speaker
```

Answer (score 0):

While quickly rewritting my question I found out what is wrong with the code.
However, the solutions provided by Ronak and markus before are more compact and make more sense.

**To do it with the loop**
I found out that some parameters were missing

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
  for(j in 1:length(list[[i]])){
    value <- data.frame(word = list[[i]][j], label = str_c(list[[i]], collapse = " "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    table <- rbind(table, value)
  }
}
```